# My CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i want to apply the following class to my image element :

```
.laptopimage {
    width: 115px;
    height: 93px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

my code in aspx.cs file :

```
Image image=new Image();
image.ImageUrl="~/Images/"+p.ImagePath;
image.CssClass = "laptopimage";
```

the resulted html code :

```
<img class="laptopimage" src="../Images/Laptop1.jpg"></img>
```

I can't understand why it doesn't apply css. The image is still displayed 1700x1700; Can someone explain why this is happening ?

Comment: Hard to debug with so little code- it may be a specificity issue, ie. another CSS rule is overriding the styles set in `laptopimage`

Comment: have you added reference of the css file ?

Comment: did you include your css file for sure?

Comment: you can try !important property

Comment: first order of business, never reference an image that has a larger resolution than the size it will be displayed on the web. one reason is it'll load slower. very unnecessary if it's just a thumbnail

Comment: May be some other style is overwriting, check debugger tool

Comment: i included the css file. it works for the other elements that i have in page.

Comment: Have you used your browser dev tools to 1. trace the traffic to ensure your CSS is downloaded. 2. inspect the element to see the final CSS being applied. The browser tools (F12 usually) will cast light on your issue very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your css and try with this. Some other css might be overiding your `laptopimage` class

```
.laptopimage {
    width: 115px !important;
    height: 93px !important;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Its generally recommended to avoid `!important` in place of improving your code and addressing the underlying conflict...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Comment: Not a good idea to just add !important willy nilly without first understanding the root cause of why your style is not being applied.

Comment: so i tried it in google chrome, and it works in google chrome. I can't understand why it doesn't work in mozzila firefox

Comment: @StefanP : In mozila press `Ctrl + shift + delete` to clear cache

Comment: and yes its not recommended to use !important. But atleast it will give you some hints about css that is overiding your current class

Comment: it works now. i cleared the cache and it is working now. I don't understand why. maybe some other class was overriding this new one.